# images show up locally but not on github pages

Tags: github-pages

I have a [website](http://calebbertrand.github.io) on github pages. Two of the images work, but one just doesn't show up. I don't think it's a problem with my code, because if I open it up the local file, it shows perfectly. Has this happened to anyone else, or am I going crazy? I'm sure the website is up-to-date.

Comment: I see three images: cannot reproduce problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [last commit](https://github.com/CalebBertrand/CalebBertrand.github.io/commit/d8f8fe5a67d12c31d45b4de8499a44c3c75cc264) refers to `imgs/coding-large.jpg` and `imgs/game-large.jpg` which do exist and do appear correctly.

But my screen is "`min-width: 500px`", so that is expected.

The last one https://calebbertrand.github.io/imgs/game.jpg is 404, because your [imgs](https://github.com/CalebBertrand/CalebBertrand.github.io/tree/master/imgs) folder include `game.JPG`.
Case (lowercase vs. uppercase) might not matter locally, at the (potentially case-insensitive) level, but it does when accessed through the web.

Comment: That worked. Also sorry you had to dig through all my unorganized code. I'm not sure how that happened, though, since in Finder the image has the name `game.jpg`. I suppose I should always check github.com to make sure.

Comment: @CalebBertrand No problem. Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer